# Check whether View is shown in Popover or in full-screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, popover, uipopover

Is there any way to check inside ViewController if it is shown in popover or in full-screen?

I tried to get and compare

```
self.view.frame.size.width
```

but sometimes it doesn't work properly, I hope there is better solution
Thanks!

Comment: which frame are you checking, the frame of view controller from which popover is presented or the frame of content view controller??

Comment: frame of content view controller

Comment: you will have to check the popover content size because  content view controller shows up only in popover content size it has showed up in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the below delegate(for popover) in your view and check if this is getting called for a popover or a view. Should be a work around I guess.

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopoverView ;
```

Comment: This function is deprecated since iOS 7